# How to use http POST data section - Java

Tags: java, http, post, https

I have many working https `POST` connections within my application, all sending simple name/value pairs in the form section.

I have been testing new communications using https://httpbin.org/post which bounces back my request so I can see how it looks.

A returned request looks like:

```
{  
    "args": {},   
    "data": "",   
    "files": {},   
    "form": {    
        "data": "Test file #1\nThis file is for testing the file uploading",     
        "name": "testFile1.txt"  
        ...
    },   
    "headers": {    
        "Accept": "text/html, image/gif, image/jpeg, *; q=.2, */*; q=.2",     
        "Content-Length": "193",     
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",     
        "Host": "httpbin.org",     
        "User-Agent": "Java/1.8.0_45"  
    },   
    "json": null,   
    ...  
    "url": "https://httpbin.org/post"
}
```

I can put data into the "form" section (as above) using `httpsConn.getOutputStream().write(data)`, where httpsConn is my HttpsURLConnection & data is my byte[] of name/value pairs.

AND I can put data into the "files" section using  (among other bits, I think these are the important pieces of code)

`request.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"data\"; filename=\"testFile1.txt\"\r\n");`
`int data;
while ((data = fileInputStream.read()) != -1) {
    request.write(data);
}`

where request is my `DataOutputStream`

The above options work to send a file in the "form" or "files" sections, however I don't really understand how it's defining in which section the information should be sent.

How would I go about adding information to the "data" or "args" sections?

Answer (score 0):

In the simple scenario where you just want data to be sent as key value pairs, use form data.. It is simple to implement and easy to work with..

However in the case when you want to send complex data like a CSV file or any such huge data, send them as files with proper content disposition as multi part data or a relevant one.

Args is usually used in the case of get request where the back end needs to send back some data based on user input.. We typically don't use args for posting data to backend as it is semantically not right..

Comment: Yes, this is what I want, to send large/complex data. I assumed it goes in the "data" section, but are you saying they should go in the "files" section? 

As I don't really understand how I got the data to switch from the "form" section to the "files" section, I can't figure out how I would choose to attach something to the "data" or "args" sections. 

Is it the Content-Disposition which defines this? If so, what would I set to use the data section?

Comment: U should set a header by name content disposition and set it to multi part data..